# Angular 7/8 File upload

Tags: angular

I have a file path like this 'C:/../data.txt' in text area
is there anyway to create and upload this file knowing only the path as described above?
I tried to use file reader but it seems that I can't read a file knowing its full path
Instead of having a browse button, I have a text area

Comment: You can't access the file system from the browser.

Comment: what i meant was that instead having a browse button i have a text area

Comment: And what I mean is that Javascript has no direct access to the file system. Your only indirect way of accessing the file system is via a `file` input. You can't give it a path, and it won't give you a path - that would be a security issue.

Comment: I think you need to create input of type file and make it hidden ,then you can trigger it's click event when text area is clicked.

Comment: thank guys. Kurt Hamilton your absolutely right, what i have saw regarding this subject was an un-editable text area. Sorry if i offended you